# python calculate decimal fraction part to arbitrary length

Tags: python, math

I am working on [Project Euler #26](https://projecteuler.net/problem=26) and need to calculate a decimal fraction part.

Using Python, how do divide 1 by 7 and tell the function to just keep giving me the decimal fraction part, until I return from the function?

Using the below I can the first 17 digits of a decimal fraction part:

```
from __future__ import division
1/7

# 0.14285714285714285
```

Instead, I want to write a function that doesn't stop until I return from it, and this function just keeps on generating the decimal fraction part.

Comment: You mean something like : `print "%.50f"%(1.0/7)`

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Totally works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate an infinite number of digits using the same method you learned in school: long division. Simply take the remainder from each division and shift it one digit (multiply by 10), and divide to get a new remainder.

```
def infinite_divide(numerator, denominator):
    if numerator > denominator:
        raise ValueError('This function only returns digits after the decimal')
    while numerator != 0:
        numerator *= 10
        digit, numerator = divmod(numerator, denominator)
        yield digit
```

Here's an example of it in use. I use `islice` to limit the results to 50 digits, otherwise it would happily keep generating digits until you ran out of memory.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> '0.' + ''.join(str(digit) for digit in islice(infinite_divide(1, 7), 50))
'0.14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714'
```

Comment: This is a better approach for this particular problem than Decimal. Leaving my answer up as well in case it's useful for others who land here, but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The comment to use float formatting won't work correctly in all cases since floats can't represent arbitrarily precise decimals (e.g., 1/7 should be a repeating decimal, but it breaks down after a while):

```
In [1]: print "%.50f"%(1.0/7)
0.14285714285714284921269268124888185411691665649414
```

You can instead use Python's built-in decimal to get arbitrary precision:

```
In [2]: from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

In [3]: Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)
Out[3]: Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')

In [4]: getcontext().prec = 100

In [5]: Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)
Out[5]: Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571429')
```

Comment: In fact a `float` breaks down even more obviously if you print more digits.  The IEEE `float` format will never have more than 54 non-zero digits, so if you used a format of `%.60f` you'd start seeing those zeros.